# Is there an easy way to access a wolkenkit application running within a VM from the host machine?

Tags: wolkenkit

I try run `wolkenkit` within a VM and access it from the host machine. So I cannot use the default local.wolkenkit.io (as it points to 127.0.0.1). I can access the VM at network-ip: 10.0.1.100 so communication between VM and host should be fine.

I tried to change the host in the package.json of the chat sample [as described in the documentation](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/latest/reference/configuring-an-application/setting-the-host-and-port/). But unfortunately I only get the error:

> "Application and Docker server do not resolve to the same IP address."

It seems like the check fails as the domain local.wolkenkit.io resolves to 127.0.0.1 which conflicts with my network-ip: 10.0.1.100.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO and please finish the tour. Enjoy your stay ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to adjust the `/etc/hosts` file so that `local.wolkenkit.io` (or whatever domain you want to use) points to the IP of your virtual machine.

(I hope that I didn't miss anything, but basically you only need to make sure that everyone (Docker, the CLI, your external clients, …) all resolve to the same IP address when using the domain name you want to use.)

Hope this helps :-)